# Missing permission to access input devices on Raspberry Pi3 B+

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have written a javafx/java program to run on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ with 7" official touchscreen. I managed to get the software to run on my PCs, installed the javafx extension for my jdk on the pi and now I'd be ready to run it. Unfortunately when I do I get the following error in the console:

> Udev: Failed to write to /sys/class/input/input3/uevent
>
> Check that you have permission to access input devices
>
> Cannot open display

I have no idea how to fix that. I tried `sudo adduser man input`, which added man to the group input, but I still get the same error.

Do you know what I need to do to acces the Touchscreen?

Comment: You need to run your app with `sudo`, as JavaFX requires write permissions to access the hardware, something like: `sudo java -jar myApp.jar`, (same for JavaFX 11, see [this post](http://docs.gluonhq.com/embedded/#_run_the_application_on_the_device))

Comment: App ran without sudo in the end, error was still shown, but the app started and worked without problems. Also i needed to use `sudo apt install raspberrypi-ui-mods` and modify the 99-com.rules first. unfortunately it has gone to shit anyways because I took the power button from my old rpi, connected it to the new one and when pressing it the thing immediately broke. Well at least it serves as my new shooting target now...